# How to make sense of `int (*pixels)[image->size_x];`?

Tags: c, pointers, declaration

A friend of mine asked me to explain to him the following excerpt (for context, I've translated the original comments and variable names):

```
typedef struct {
    int size_x, size_y, shades;
    void * pixels;
} t_image;

int read(FILE * file, t_image * image) {
    // ...
    /* we allocate a sufficiently large array */
    image->pixels = malloc(image->size_x * image->size_y * sizeof(int));
    /* and just now we declare an auxiliary pointer to the array */
    /* of known dimensions, we will access it only through that pointer */
    // MY COMMENT: HERE COME THE WEIRD LINES
    int (*pixels)[image->size_x]; /* pixels in the image struct */
    pixels = (int(*)[image->size_x]) image->pixels; /* we initialise it as we should */
    // ...
}
```

What is this, declaring and dereferencing a pointer all in one go? It looks a bit like a function pointer, but not really, since it contains `[image->size_x]` and not `(image->size_x)`.

Comment: It's a declaration of a pointer to an array, so it can be used to walk through an array of arrays, i.e. the rows of a two-dimensional array.

Comment: `/* we initialise it as we should */` is useless comment. What does "should" mean? Comments should explain more - simply repeating what the code does adds nothing.  And the comment is not quite right as the line is performing an assignment, not an initialisation.  `int (*pixels)[image->size_x] = image->pixels;` would be an initialisaion.  Note that the cast from `void *` is not necessary in C.

Comment: @AndrewHenle I'd love to tell you what "should" means, but I don't know either. The code was written by a lecturer and the students were expected to just cut and paste it into their own programs. Whether they understood it was not the concern.

Comment: @NateEldredge could you break it down a little? I don't see how the types and variables relate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
// declare a pointer to an array of array of ints of size image->size_x
int (*pixels)[image->size_x];

// assign image->pixels to pixels
// since image->pixels is of type void*, you have to cast it
pixels = (int(*)[image->size_x]) image->pixels;
```

Then you can access the rows of the image by

```
pixels[row];
```

and iterate row by row, by

```
pixels++;
```

and lastly access a specific pixel by

```
pixels[row][col];

// or of the active row
(*pixels)[col];
```

**Based on your comment:**

`int pixels[image->size_x][]` is not equivalent to `int (*pixels)[image->size_x]`.

`int (*pixels)[image->size_x]` is equivalent to `int pixels[][image->size_x]`.

Basically like `char *str[80]` is equivalent to `char str[][80]`;
An array of strings of each length of 80 characters.

Comment: Wait, would `int pixels[image->size_x][]` be equivalent to `int (*pixels)[image->size_x]`?

Comment: I've added an answer to your question.

Comment: The equivalency you added is not correct except in context of function arguments where arrays don't exist and are just syntactic sugar for the pointer type they would decay to.

Comment: @R.. GitHub STOP HELPING ICE Could you elaborate further please? Sure, pointer != array, and an array can decay (and will, if used as function argument) to a pointer. But equivalency is used here (at least for my understanding) as 'think of it as'. If i got something wrong, please let me know.

Comment: @ErdalKüçük: A huge amount of erroneous reasoning about C comes out of thinking of pointers and arrays as the same thing. They're not, and pointer-to-array types like in this question are one of the best illustrations.